# Removing a single extended permission from Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

So it seems I can destroy all permissions to the app entirely with a DELETE request to /me/permissions, however I want the ability to just remove publish_stream for a user, without linking them to the app settings page.

The old REST API [had a way of doing this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeExtendedPermission/), and the page also states:

'You can issue an HTTP DELETE request to /PROFILE_ID/permissions with the specific permission as parameter to revoke that extended permission for an app.'

My 2 questions are; what IS the parameter to specify a single permission (so far anything that gets sent as a DELETE request destroys everything), and where the hell is the documentation for it? =\

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions

Comment: Hero, thanks! Been looking for that for days. If you put this as a full answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete single permissions by issuing a DELETE request to `/PROFILE_ID/permissions/PERMISSION_NAME`

The documentation for this is in the description of the `user` part of the API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions